# Load testing of a web Application for 500 users in one go by selenium-jmete

Tags: selenium, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I need to test a web application functionality for uploading patch file for more than 500 users in one time, i tried to do by selenium Jmeter combination, but when i run for 500 threads, it invokes 500 chrome browser and system hangs, any idea how to overcome this or any workaround for this

Comment: Did you consider headless mode for this ?

Comment: @cruisepandey yes tried that as well, system hangs is backend it also opens the chrome browser

Comment: @Prophet : I would like it more if SO launches reaction on comments, I would love to react :D on it. jk

Comment: it would cause you are saying Hey system I am launching a rocket, and your system is like 1975 RAM, could not do it :D

Answer (score 0):

[Chrome System Requirements](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7100626?hl=en) page states that you need `An Intel Pentium 4 processor or later that's SSE3 capable` to launch an instance of the browser. It means [one CPU core per browser instance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) plus one core (at least) for JMeter to work.

Chrome System Requirements doesn't tell anything about RAM usage, however you can open the system under test in Chrome manually and check the consumed memory using i.e. [Resource Monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Monitor). Once you have the number of megabytes (I believe in case of Chrome it will rather be gigabytes) - multiply them by 500 and this is how many RAM you will need. [Firefox 90](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/90.0/system-requirements/) needs 2 gigabytes per instance, generally Chrome requires more.

So the question is: does the machine where you run JMeter has 501 CPU cores and a terabyte of RAM?

- If yes - consider following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
- If no - consider [converting your Selenium tests into "pure" JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter) and this way you will be able to simulate 500 concurrent file uploads from low-end laptop